# Is there an "Add Data Widget" equivalent for the ArcGIS Server JavaScript API?

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, widget

The ArcGIS Web AppBuilder has an [Add Data widget](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/web-appbuilder/create-apps/widget-add-data.htm) which:

> allows you to add data to the map by searching for layers in ArcGIS content, entering URLs, or uploading local files. In this way, you can temporarily add layers to and remove layers from the map

Before I reinvent the wheel, is there an out-of-the-box equivalent for the ArcGIS Server JavaScript API version 4?

There's nothing listed in the Widgets section for version 4.23 at https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/

Comment: How about an approach to use the Layer List widget as a starting point and to add in modules used in the Add Data widget? In order to search for layers in the portal, you would need to use the queryItems() method of the Portal class. https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/portal-amd.html#queryitems

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Note that I'm using version 4 of the API so the equivalent `queryItems` method is https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-portal-Portal.html#queryItems

Comment: The equivalent of the WAB "Add Data widget" would probably be the ExperienceBuilder (ExB) widget: https://doc.arcgis.com/en/web-appbuilder/create-apps/widget-add-data.htm